# Desactivar celdas anteriores a la celda seleccionada - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, selectores-css

Estoy creando un calendario con **JQuery**.

Este es el código:

```
<div id="dncalendar-body" class="dncalendar-body">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>D</td>
                <td>L</td>
                <td>M</td>
                <td>M</td>
                <td>J</td>
                <td>V</td>
                <td>S</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="" data-date="30" data-month="9" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">30</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="1" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">1</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="2" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">2</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="3" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">3</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="4" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">4</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="5" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">5</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="6" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">6</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="" data-date="7" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">7</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="8" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">8</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="9" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">9</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="10" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">10</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="11" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">11</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="12" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">12</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="13" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">13</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="" data-date="14" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">14</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="15" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">15</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" today-date  calendarClick" data-date="16" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry" data-title="hoy">16</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" calendarClick" data-date="17" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">17</div>
                </td>
                <td id="" class="" data-date="18" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">18</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" calendarClick" data-date="19" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">19</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" calendarClick" data-date="20" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">20</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" calendarClick" data-date="21" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">21</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" calendarClick" data-date="22" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">22</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" calendarClick" data-date="23" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">23</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" calendarClick" data-date="24" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">24</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" calendarClick" data-date="25" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">25</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" calendarClick" data-date="26" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">26</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" calendarClick" data-date="27" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">27</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" calendarClick" data-date="28" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">28</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" calendarClick" data-date="29" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">29</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" calendarClick" data-date="30" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">30</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" calendarClick" data-date="31" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">31</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" " data-date="1" data-month="11" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">1</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" " data-date="2" data-month="11" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">2</div>
                </td>
                <td id="calendarClick" class=" " data-date="3" data-month="11" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">3</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/MDcalendar.js"></script>

</body></html>
```

Quisiera saber la forma de bloquear los tb anteriores al tb que yo seleccione con click

Yo le asigné a las celdas que se pueden cliquear un id y una clase llamada *CalendarClick*, si estas clases son removidas entonces, esas celdas ya no podran ser seleccionadas.

Pero no se que selector **JQuery**debo utilizar para quitar el id y la clase de los tb anteriores al que seleccioné

Hago esto para reconocer que celda he seleccionado

```
$('body').on('click', '#calendarClick', function(){  
    $(this).css("background", "#00FF00");
});
```

He leido un poco de los selectores **JQuery** pero aun no logro entenderlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En primer lugar, es muy mala práctica asignar el mismo `id` a múltiples elementos en una misma página. Es preferible que el selector funcione con el atributo `class`, el cual si puede repetirse para múltiples elementos.

Podés deshabilitar los elementos anteriores al item seleccionado obteniendo el índice del mismo y aplicando una acción a los elementos obtenidos por el selector [`:lt()`](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/), sin incluir el separador de filas `tr`. Algo así:

```js
$('body').on('click', '.calendarClick', function() {
  $('table tbody td').removeClass('deshabilitado');
  
  let index = $('table tbody td').index(this);
  $('table tbody td:lt(' + index + ')').addClass('deshabilitado');
})
```

```css
.calendarClick{
  color: #0000dd;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

table tbody td.deshabilitado{
   color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>D</td>
                <td>L</td>
                <td>M</td>
                <td>M</td>
                <td>J</td>
                <td>V</td>
                <td>S</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="" data-date="30" data-month="9" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">30</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="1" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">1</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="2" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">2</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="3" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">3</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="4" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">4</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="5" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">5</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="6" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">6</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="" data-date="7" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">7</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="8" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">8</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="9" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">9</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="10" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">10</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="11" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">11</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="12" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">12</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="13" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">13</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="" data-date="14" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">14</div>
                </td>
                <td class="" data-date="15" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">15</div>
                </td>
                <td class=" today-date  calendarClick" data-date="16" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry" data-title="hoy">16</div>
                </td>
                <td class=" calendarClick" data-date="17" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">17</div>
                </td>
                <td id="" class="" data-date="18" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">18</div>
                </td>
                <td class=" calendarClick" data-date="19" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">19</div>
                </td>
                <td class=" calendarClick" data-date="20" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">20</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class=" calendarClick" data-date="21" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">21</div>
                </td>
                <td class=" calendarClick" data-date="22" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">22</div>
                </td>
                <td class=" calendarClick" data-date="23" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">23</div>
                </td>
                <td class=" calendarClick" data-date="24" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">24</div>
                </td>
                <td class=" calendarClick" data-date="25" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">25</div>
                </td>
                <td class=" calendarClick" data-date="26" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">26</div>
                </td>
                <td class=" calendarClick" data-date="27" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">27</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class=" calendarClick" data-date="28" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">28</div>
                </td>
                <td class=" calendarClick" data-date="29" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">29</div>
                </td>
                <td class=" calendarClick" data-date="30" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">30</div>
                </td>
                <td class=" calendarClick" data-date="31" data-month="10" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">31</div>
                </td>
                <td class=" " data-date="1" data-month="11" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">1</div>
                </td>
                <td class=" " data-date="2" data-month="11" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">2</div>
                </td>
                <td class=" " data-date="3" data-month="11" data-year="2018">
                    <div class="entry">3</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: No sabia lo del mismo ID, entones lo voy a cambiar, gracias por enseñarme .